# In Linux trying to output manual pages in different encodings

Tags: linux

In the moment using KNOPPIX 9.1, else Kubuntu 22.04.

I would like to get mamual pages in different encodings by the option in command man:

```
man -R ascii -L en <manpage>    
man -R latin1 -L en <manpage>    
man -R iso8895-1 -L en <manpage>
```

In all three cases I get the same output (as compared with diff).

The command "file" says that it is "ascii".

Pehaps my specification of the ENCODING is incorrect.
But there is nowhere a documentation how to write the parameter for using in

man -R

Regards

antonhdidh

Answer (score 0):

solved:

First the utility "mandoc" is to be installed.

Then in order to get the formatted output of the english manpage, e.g. "bash", in ascii (encoding iso8859-1 not possible), use this code:

```
man -L en --no-hyphenation --no-justification bash | mandoc -c -O width=$COLUMNS -T ascii | col -b -x >/tmp/WEx1
```

===

Mamy yeaers ago I had a simpler way, without mandoc. It was by controllimg groff or troff or nroff.

I cannot find my old code and cannot re-develop. If someone kows that way, I would be gratefull.

Regards

antondhidh